# SQL and LUIS API

Tags: sql, text-analysis, azure-language-understanding

Ok this may be me not understanding things, happens a lot as I'm new at stuff, but what I have is a database in both OLTP and OLAP formats.

I've done some googling and found that I can configure them to be exposed to a http endpoint so my question is, can I expose them to the LUIS http API endpoint?

Essentially I want to use the service to be trained as people ask questions of my data. I deal a lot with hospital data so it would be things `matching intentions of Diagnosis of chest pains = complaining of chest pain`.

I don't a full detailed answer of how to do it if it is  possible, rather I'm more interested in a straight yes or no ,so I can  know whether to dig into this or not. Text analytics is next on my list, but it doesn't have the ability to start learn what the intention and why people are asking the question like LUIS does.